# How to fix Run button in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Pressing Run button in Intllij - it becomes grey without actions. Same happens to Debug button. Main method exists.

Only 'Run with Coverage' worked for me.

I tried to restart Intellij.

Comment: What have you tried to solve it? Restarting Intellij? Reimporting? Removing iml files and .idea directory?

Comment: Do you use some build tools (maven, gradle)? Does the run configuration in intelliJ points to the main class? Was there any code/environment change between when it was starting and now? And try the tips from above comment.

Comment: @JasperHuzen restart didnt help, 'Run with coverage' worked for me

Comment: Could also be caused by a bad Maven pom structure. Sometimes a manual "mvn install" in the root of your project will help.

Comment: @JasperHuzen used Gradle

Comment: @itwasntme No, yesterday worked, 0 changes - no didnt work

Comment: only Run with Coverage works, other not

Comment: Have you updated intellij maybe? There's know issue in IntelliJ when using gradle and running the main class (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-226836). It was fixed but still not released. Maybe change your run configuration from main class to use the gradle task which starts the app.

Comment: @itwasntme i have no errors, just cant start project. Clean-build successfully

Comment: @itwasntme I deleted main class, created again - now Debuger works too, Run - not

Comment: Please try to run "File | Invalidate Caches". Also please check idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") for errors/warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only restarting system solved my problem.